# How to adjust the width of each plan on responsive pricing table Wordpress plugin by Darko

Tags: wordpress, plugins, responsive

I am trying to use responsive pricing table by Wordpress Darko, although I have set just one table with multiple plans it is still stacked vertically where each plan takes up full width of the page. How can you fix this?

Comment: it's probably your resolution.

Comment: My bad. it was because i created 6 plans but the plugin support only 5.